# How to make OSX open the same bundle twice?

Tags: macos, shared-libraries, bundle, audiounit, vst

I have 2 bundles with the exact same contents, just copied them to a different folders and renamed appropriately (these are audio plugins to be specific). A host opens one bundle, that's correct, but then when it should open the second one, it actually seems to just attach the first one already loaded. But I need it to open the second one too. I tried to rename it, change props... nothing... it still just uses the already loaded one instead of loading the second one too. How can I do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try either of those?:

1. run the bundle from Terminal: open my_app.app --new
   (the --new flag should force a new instance)
2. 'duplicate' (right click) instread of 'copy' in the finder

Comment: Thanks. The problem is it's not an app, but a plugin, hence a dynamic library. I tried to tamper the Info.plist changing the bundle identifier, but that didn't help either. I need to find a way to do it technically, duplicating in finder wouldn't really help, even if it would work.